# Can't run iOS 16 simulator on Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I downloaded Xcode 14 beta and I have my Visual Studio pointing to that as the SDK location. I don't see any simulators to run in the drop down. Using VS Mac 2022 fully updated. I did notice in the simulator drop down for 'iOS Simulators: Lower the deployment target to see the older target or check your Apple SDK Path'.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the preview channel for VS Mac?

Comment: I have tried both and they both don't work

Comment: If you want to simply target iOS 15.x Simulators instead, you can install Xcode 13.x from the App Store and select it in Visual Studio for Mac 2022's settings, then restart the IDE. This should be enough in most cases, however If they still don't appear, you can fix it by running the following in Terminal: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, however do note that this may break other features, such as Homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be an official Visual Studio/Xamarin.iOS update out yet that supports iOS 16 and XCode 14 which I believe will be first available on the preview channel.  According to this, this situation is not entirely unexpected: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Xcode-Summer-Expectations  although like you, there are issues with our Xamarin app in iOS 16 that need to be addressed, and I am anxiously awaiting official support.

If you need to get the simulator running you can follow the advice here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15581 and download the PKG-Xamarin.iOS-notorizied.pkg package on the the xcode14 branch of xamarin-macios https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/commits/xcode14  Once I installed the pkg, the simulators were available. It is worth noting that you also need to have the xcode 14 beta installed, and may need to change your SDK path in Visual Studio to the xcode 14 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, the only alternative that I found is to deploy the application on a physical device that runs iOS 16 beta version and test it.